# Recurring Contributions for PayflowPro

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, paypal, recurring-contributions

We are using the Payflow Pro Processor, including for recurring donations.

Until recently there weren't any issues. But now, when a donor selects for recurring payments the processor always throws following error: `Payment Processor Error message :9013: Error – from payment processor: [7 Field format error: Invalid or missing START/NEXTPAYMENTDATE field]`.

This is independent of whether I enabled selecting a period and installments or not.

We use the standard class for this `civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayflowPro.php`. We had also developed our own class, which included `NEXTPAYMENT` as an option to be passed to PayPal.

Do we need to fiddle with your standard class, or is there a setting we miss?

Comment: CiviCRM is an open source project, so you're very welcome to submit your fixes and improvements. Good starting places are probably: [How to contribute](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/core/contributing/), [CiviCRM issue tracker](https://issues.civicrm.org) and [CiviCRM chat](https://chat.civicrm.org).